# How to define custom tempdir

Tags: r

I am a user (no admin privileges) of an Ubuntu 12.04.4 machine running R 3.1.

I find I can't start R because `Fatal error: cannot create 'R_TempDir`. The problem is pretty simple (and [already documented here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11979631/1707938)): there's not enough disk space to initialize R temporary directory. Indeed:

```
df /tmp
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1       10320184 10284088         0 100% /
```

But then I have plenty of space on a different partition (`/dev/vdb`). How could I tell R to create a temporary folder in a different location?

Since I can't start R, I tried to set in my `.Rprofile`

```
.First <- function(){
  ## other stuff
  tempdir("path/to/plenty/of/space/tmp")
  ## other stuff
}
```

Yet it doesn't work.

```
Error in tempdir("path/to/plenty/of/space/tmp") : 
  unused argument ("path/to/plenty/of/space/tmp")
Calls: .First -> tempdir
Execution halted
```

EDIT: Question already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17108351/1707938).
Create a `.Rprofile` and add this line `TMP = '<your-desired-tempdir>'`

Answer (score 4):

`tempdir()` only returns the temp directory, and cannot change it, event does not get an argument.

But here is a section of manual of the same function, you can see the complete manual using `?tempdir`

> when the R session is started. The environment variables TMPDIR, TMP
>   and TEMP are checked in turn and the first found which points to a
>   writable directory is used: if none succeeds ‘/tmp’ is used.

Hence you need to set the environmental variable TMPDIR