# How to fix Fatal error: cannot create 'R_TempDir'?

Tags: r, linux, server

I am working on my data science work on a linux server but I know very little about linux. When I submit my Rscript I got this Error:

```
Fatal error: cannot create 'R_TempDir'
```

However, I can directly open R like this:

```
[xxx@x xxx]$ R

R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21) -- "You Stupid Darkness"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

Here is some more information:

```
[xxx@x xxx]$ df -lh /tmp
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/os_vg-lvTmp
                      9.8G   52M  9.2G   1% /tmp
```

Could you please kindly give me the **detailed** instructions on how to fix this fatal error? Since I am really puzzled about how the system work or not work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you share directory permissions ? `ls -l ..` and `pwd` commands would be helpful. Be sure to run these commands on the same directory you are trying to run the R program. Btw can you share the code or show where your code tries to create a directory ?

Comment: Make sure that permissions for `/tpm` have write permission for your user. Something along the lines of `sudo chmod +w /tmp`.

Comment: See: [Fatal error: cannot mkdir R_TempDir](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6307836/10488504)

Comment: @Catastrophe Here are the results:
`[user@master CODE]$ ls -l ..     total 8     drwxrwxr-x 4 user user 4096 Apr 13 16:33 CODE     drwxrwxr-x 6 user user 4096 Apr 13 10:48 Rlib`
and 
`[user@master CODE]$ pwd     /data/user/CODE`
I am not creating a directory in my R code, in fact, when I am running the code like this`"=========" ` I still got this error.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Thanks for your help, but sorry I have no sudo access.

Comment: @GKi Thanks! I tried some of solutions in the referred question, but they didn't work. Besides when it comes to environment variables, I am really confused about what exactly should I do.